Oracle BI Publisher 12.2.1.2.0 scheduled reports hang at a status of 'Running', and never complete or progress to an error status
people. I have found an article (https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Oracle%20E-Business%20Suite/2238710_1.html) which can help me, but I don't have Oracle support corporate account. Can anyone send me copy of the article, or tell me short about solution Oracle provides
BI Publisher have been installed from scratch. Reports have been exported for BI Publisher 11.1.1.7 and imported into BI Publisher 12.2.1.2.0
I've tried to invoke ScheduleReportInSession method of BI Publisher SOAP endpoint http://localhost:9502/xmlpserver/services/v2/ScheduleService, report successfully scheduled but hang at a status of 'Running'
